# ember-data: how to get embedded json

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

My Json Data looks like this:

```
 {"user":{"id":1,
        "name":"bob",
        "profile":{"id":1,
                "forename":"Foo",
                "surname":"Bar",
                "user_id":1}}
```

My model looks like:

```
 App.User = DS.Model.extend({
     name: DS.attr('string'),
     profile: DS.belongsTo('App.Profile')
 });
```

and

```
 App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
     forename: DS.attr('string'),
     surname: DS.attr('string'),,
     user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
 });
```

When I try to get `{{user.name}}`, it works fine. `user.profile.forename` doesnt work. I tried for my user model

```
 DS.AuthenticatedRESTAdapter.map('App.User', {
     profile: {embedded: true}
 });
```

as well, but still doenst work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is missing is configuring the serializer (used by the adapter) by calling its 'map' function:

```
App.MySerializer = DS.Serializer.extend({
    init: function(){
      this._super();
      this.map(App.User, {
        profile: {
          embedded: 'load'
        }
      });
    }
});
```

You can find a working example at JFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/olmeca/7qTty/1/).

Comment: Alternatively you can call map() on the RESTAdapter (or your subclass thereof) with the same parameters as above. This way you don't need to subclass the RESTSerializer (new in version 10). Make sure you call map() on the class, not an instance. I have tested this with version 10 of ember-data.

Comment: Since I wrote this post the Ember Data code base has changed significantly. So much so that I doubt this approach would still apply.